# Tensorflow: read raw file with uint8 and float32

Tags: tensorflow

It's easy to read raw file consists values of single type, uint8 or int32, etc.

```
record = tf.reshape(tf.decode_raw(data, tf.uint8), [record_bytes])
```

Now if the each record consists of uint8 data and float32 labels, how to read it correctly?

Ex: format of each record is:

```
data         label
2048 uint8   8 floats
total bytes of each record = 2048 + 8*4 = 2072
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tf.substr()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/substr) operation to select the appropriate ranges of bytes from the record, then use [`tf.decode_raw()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_raw) twice with the different types. For example, assuming your raw data is in a `tf.string` tensor called `data`:

```
features = tf.decode_raw(tf.substr(data, 0, 2048), tf.uint8)
label = tf.decode_raw(tf.substr(data, 2048, 32), tf.float32)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.   Is it possible to decode multiple records like this and feed them as batches into RandomShuffleQueue for training?

Comment: Yes. Although we now recommend that you use `tf.data.Dataset` for building pipelines. The `tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset` may be most useful for your case.